# Load image to div without refreshing browser

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, server-sent-events

What is the best way to update path to image using PHP (web sockets, server-sent events, etc.) without refreshing browser?

I have 10 divs in which i have to load path to image and show that image. I don't have to worry about support on different web browsers because i will install it on those PC's that will display this web site (20-30 PC's).

So, I just need your opinion on best technology to load image on div (on event sent from server application) without refreshing it.

Btw: There will be 50 different images and `all` will be already in a folder on site root.

Comment: there's no way to do that in php, that's for javascript for

Comment: in which events do you have to update path to images ?

Comment: on server sent events... my app (PHP) will check for new updates in DB and if there are updates I need to send event to website to change image.

Comment: u cud use node js for that. node js application can listen to any database change and trigger events based on the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do that in php, that's what javascript is for.

```
document.getElementById("myimg").src = "newimage.jpg";
```

i reply to the comment:

```
$('img').each(function(){ 
    var source = $(this).parent().find('span').first().val();    //if spans contain picture names
    $(this).attr("src",source);
});
```

if you can use id's

```
document.getElementById("first").src = "15.jpg";
document.getElementById("second").src = "10.jpg";
document.getElementById("third").src = "21.jpg";
...
```

another reply to the comments. To invoke javascript on php:

```
if ($invoke_javascript): ?>
    <script>
        alert('javascript goes here');
    </script>
<?php endif;
```

Comment: How would i do it lets say here:
    `<li><img src="Small/1.png"><span>10.000</span></li>
    <li><img src="Small/2.png"><span>7.500</span></li>
    <li><img src="Small/3.png"><span>5.000</span></li>`

If I need to load images 15.png, 10.png, 21.png

Comment: it would be easyer if you'd use id's on these images

Comment: in jQuery it would be like that $('img').each(function(){ var source = $(this).parent().find('span).first().val(); $(this).attr("src",source);});

Comment: ok, so i'll add li#one, li#two, li#three and then just connect id to js?

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try this. Just one more question. How can i send info from my server to invoke this function? Basicaly what i need is, when I check my database for new row in some table i want to send event for webpage to change picture in this <li>.

Comment: Thank you mister :) you're a gem

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this in jQuery:

```
$(".my-div img").attr("src", "/new/image.jpg");
```